# Encrypting a file with Nodejs (Crypto) throw an error: bad base64 decode

Tags: node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg, cryptojs

Hello and sorry if my question is stupid, I'm just beginning on nodejs and bring a heavy luggage from PHP world.

I'm trying to encrypt a file using a public key generated through linux command line using the GnuPG command.

On my app I use Express, fs and Crypto to create a buffer from the file and get the public key content and then use publicEncrypt to get the encrypted data.

When I do so the application stops and throw an error complaining about the PEM format: bad base64 decode.

```
Error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
```

Here you have the main parts of this code:

```
var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey);
var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
if(typeof toEncrypt !=='object') return false;
var buffer = new Buffer(toEncrypt);
console.log(publicKey);
var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
return encrypted.toString("base64");
```

};

```
        fs.readFile(req.files[0].path, function (err, data){
            var encrypted = encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey(data, '/home/app/data/pub_key.txt');
            if(!encrypted) {
                fs.writeFile("/home/app/data/uploads/enc1/test.pdf", encrypted, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }

                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                    res.end(req.files[0].filename);
                }); 
            }
            else {
                res.end({error:'encryption failed. all data deleted.'});
            }
        });
```

Maybe the Public Key has some end of line bad characters somewhere or maybe Crypto requires a very special format?

This is the content of the pub key:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=rpky
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: Data such as file contents are generally encrypted with symmetric algorithms such as AES which have no data size limitations. Asymmetric encryption such as RSA is generally used to encrypt symmetric keys and the data size is limited to less than the key size.

Comment: Check the documentation for CryptoJS -- it may expect an RSA key and not be able to handle the GPG version comment (which is not Base64-encoded).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to my problem.

In fact the method publicEncrypt is a wrapper of OpenSSL and then it expect a public/private key on that format. A key from GPG won't do it.

By generating the private and public keys with the following command the code work as expected:

```
$ openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
$ openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```